# Контроль времени просмотра рекламы из тг бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Телеграмм бот сообщением присылает рекламу через message_answer (ссылку на внешний ресурс). Как реализовать контроль, понять, что пользователь полностью ее посмотрел, и только потом присылать следующее сообщение?
Бот на aiogram

Comment: "Внешний ресурс" ваш, или сторонний?

Comment: Вообще сторонний, но интересен был бы и ответ, если свой

Comment: Если сторонний, то крайне важно какой именно.